# Grails data won't bind if the id column is renamed

Tags: grails

Grails will create an id and a version columns from a domain class automatically.  I want to use my own column for the primary key.  So, I follow the doc to change the mapping.

```
class book {
    String isbn
    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'isbn'
    }
}
```

So far so good.  The isbn column is now the primary key.
I use generate-all to create the view and controller.  However, the data binding won't work anymore.

Create and Save work no problem. It binds a book to the view.  I can add a new book to the database no problem.

```
def create() {
   respond new Book(params)
}

def save(Book book) {
   if (book == null) {
      notFound()
      return
   }
   ...
}
```

But the Update action does not bind.  book is null after I click the Update button from the Edit view.

```
def update(Book book) {
   if (book == null) {
      notFound()
      return
   }
   ...
}
```

The codes generated by generate-all in the Save and Update actions are the same.  I don't understand why it will bind the book to the Save action but not to Update action.

Would you show me the problem please?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Does `params` include a value for `params.id`, `params.isbn`, both, or neither?  Same question for form fields if this is a POST/PUT request.

Comment: Yes, `params` is filled out by the view.  `params.id` is null.  `params.isbn` is filled out.  My book domain does not have an `id` field.  I replaced the `id` field with a `isbn` String field.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figure it out.  When I bind an object to a view, Grails is hardcoded to look for the **id** property.  It has to be spelled "id".  If there is no "id" property in the domain class, Grails will not bind.

The way I figure this out is to look at the actual HTML generated by the server.

If there is an id property bind to the view, I see the HTML has the **../controller/action/id** link.

If the id property is missing, the HTML link is just **../controller/index**

I am new to Grails. So, I guess in order for the binding to work, I need to have an id property for Grails to put in the link.

I think this is a REST call. I don't know what REST is though.

So, I will try to add an dummy id property to my Book domain class to see if Grails will take the bait. I will set up the domain so Grails won't generate the id column in the database table. The id property is used locally only. No need to save it to the database.

```
class book {
    String isbn
    String id
    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'isbn'
    }
}
```

I will copy the isbn value to the id property.  I am not sure if this will work or not. I hope Grails will generate the link in the view with the isbn string in the id property instead of the default integer id value.
**../controller/action/978-3-16-148410-0**